# UITableViewCell using QuickDialog : handle touch event on all the cell's surface

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, quickdialog

I use custom cell on UITableView using QuickDialog

In this custom cell I have several UILabel, UIImageView and a button which has the cell size and display on the top of the others subviews.

I want this button handle touch envent and call a selector. But even though the button is at the top position, the touch event does not trigger when I touch a subview.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)getCellForTableView:(QuickDialogTableView *)tableView controller:(QuickDialogController *)controller
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super getCellForTableView:tableView controller:controller];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = cell.frame;

    [btn setEnabled:YES];
    [btn setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; // To check if the button is at the top position
    [btn setStringTag:labelIdText];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:label1];
    [cell addSubview:label2];
    [cell addSubview:image1];
    [cell addSubview:image2];
    [cell addSubview:btn];

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

The selector :

```
- (IBAction)handleTap:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"CELL TAPPED : \n");
}
```

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT :**

New version of the code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)getCellForTableView:(QuickDialogTableView *)tableView controller:(QuickDialogController *)controller
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super getCellForTableView:tableView controller:controller];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIView *top = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [top setStringTag:labelIdText];
    [top addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:label_1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label_2];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image_1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image_2];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:top];

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    image_1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    image_2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

The selector :

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    NSLog(@"CELL TAPPED : \n");
}
```

The event is handle when I touch the text containing in the UILabel.
But it's still don't work with the UIImageView despite userInteractionEnabled setted to YES for the images.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams you are assigning to the button the cell frame and then add it to the cell itself. In this way the position of the button is not the one you expect, and even though you can see the button  it will not respond to touch because it resides outside the cell bounds.
Try to change this:

```
btn.frame = cell.frame;
```

to this:

```
btn.frame = cell.bounds;
```

Also when working with UItableViewCell remember to add subviews to its contentView and not the cell itself:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:aCustomView];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately i've got still exactly the same problem.

Comment: try also [cell.contentView addSubview:...];

Comment: With [cell.contentView addSubview:...]; there is improvements but there is still problem. You can see the last version of the code et more explanations about the problem in the EDIT of my first post.

Comment: tap gesture recognizers need number of touches and taps:
    [singleFingerTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [singleFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

Comment: top view doesn't seam to be added to the stack, so the gesture recognizer is never triggered.